# A detail in the proof of Lifting Lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the Lifting Lemma (Munkres's book, page 388, Lemma 54.1), when $\tilde{f}(s)$ is constructed in each $[s_i,s_{i+1}]$, how are you sure that is well-define in the limit points $s_i,s_{i+1}$, for any $i$?

Comment: Check out the pasting lemma. Well-definedness as a set map should be given by construction.

Comment: But, taking into account the construction, you could have $\tilde{f}(s_i) = (p|_{V_0})^{-1}(f(s)) \neq (p|_{V_1})^{-1}(f(s)) = \tilde{f}(s_i)$, yeah?

Comment: That is, for $[s_1,s_2]$ you assign $\tilde{f}(s) := (p|_{V_1})^{-1}(f(s))$ and for $[s_2,s_3]$ is $\tilde{f}(s) := (p|_{V_2})^{-1}(f(s))$. So, what image you assign to $s_2$?